# Injecting JavaScript for selecting the option button using UiPath Inject JS Activity

Tags: javascript, automation, robotics, uipath

I am trying to automate one of the business process using UiPath. One of the requirement was to select the option button "Containing" as shown below.

[image]

In UiPath, there is a activity to **InJect JS** on a webpage and i would like to use this activity. For this to work, i need to write a JavaScript to select the option.

HTML tag for the radio button is below :

```
<INPUT type="radio" value="containing" name="selSearchField" ></Input>
```

Please help me with the JS Code

Comment: you can inject jquery with InjectJs and easily select radio button using jquery. check out this   http://www.injectjs.com/docs/0.7.x/howto/inject_and_libraries.html

Comment: Hi Sandy, i am very new to JS and trying to learn the programming. What code would help me click the radio button ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
function check() 
{
 if(document.readyState === "complete") 
 {
    document.getElementsByName("selSearchField")[1].checked = true;
  }
}
```